# Card-Sorting tool that allows making cards categories

Tags: card-sorting

I am surprised that none of the many tools I just tested offers this functionality.
See this image for comprehension:
[image]

The user is supposed to be able to make any of the cards a category.
Anyone have a suggestion?

(Of course a test in real world would be better, but the requirement ist web-based)

Comment: Hi Big_Chair. What is your question? Are you asking if something like this exists? How to implement something like this?

Comment: Traditional card sorts do not provide the instruction that a participant can "make any of the cards a category", which is why you are not finding tools that support the functionality. A card sort either (1) asks the user to define categories themselves, or (2) provides defined categories for the participant to sort into.

Comment: as @EvilClosetMonkey says, this isn't sorting, it's nesting.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Optimal Workshop. This is a screenshot of their card sorting tool (Called [Optimal Sort](https://www.optimalworkshop.com/optimalsort/))

Here is a screenshot of the tool:
[image]